# Laravel: Looping through an array and converting it to a modified array with original array inside a key

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have a data array that contains food items and looks like this.

```
[
  {
    "itemId": 80001,
    "name": "FRENCH FRIES SMALL",
    "description": "More delicious than ever, our signature piping hot, thick cut Salted French Fries are golden on the outside and fluffy on the inside.",
    "price": 6,
    "slug": "french-fries-small-80001"
  },
  {
    "itemId": 80002,
    "name": "FRENCH FRIES MEDIUM",
    "description": "More delicious than ever, our signature piping hot, thick cut Salted French Fries are golden on the outside and fluffy on the inside.",
    "price": 7,
    "slug": "french-fries-medium-80002"
  },
  {
    "itemId": 80003,
    "name": "FRENCH FRIES LARGE",
    "description": "More delicious than ever, our signature piping hot, thick cut Salted French Fries are golden on the outside and fluffy on the inside.",
    "price": 8,
    "slug": "french-fries-large-80003"
  },
  {
    "itemId": 80052,
    "name": "CRINCKLE WEDGES SMALL",
    "description": "CRINCKLE WEDGES SMALL",
    "price": 7,
    "slug": "crinckle-wedges-small-80052",
    "sequence": 14
  },
  {
    "itemId": 80053,
    "name": "CRINCKLE WEDGES MEDIUM",
    "description": "CRINCKLE WEDGES MEDIUM",
    "price": 8,
    "slug": "crinckle-wedges-medium-80053",
    "sequence": 15
  },
  {
    "itemId": 80054,
    "name": "CRINCKLE WEDGES LARGE",
    "description": "CRINCKLE WEDGES LARGE",
    "price": 9,
    "slug": "crinckle-wedges-large-80054",
    "sequence": 16
  },

]
```

Now I have to loop through that array and if the name has either SMALL, MEDIUM, or LARGE I have to reformat the data so that it should look something like this e.g.

```
{
  "itemId": 80001,
  "name": "FRENCH FRIES",
  "description": "More delicious than ever, our signature piping hot, thick cut Salted French Fries are golden on the outside and fluffy on the inside.",
  "itemModifiers": [
    {
      "itemId": 80001,
      "name": "FRENCH FRIES SMALL",
      "description": "More delicious than ever, our signature piping hot, thick cut Salted French Fries are golden on the outside and fluffy on the inside.",
      "price": 6,
      "slug": "french-fries-small-80001"
    },
    {
      "itemId": 80002,
      "name": "FRENCH FRIES MEDIUM",
      "description": "More delicious than ever, our signature piping hot, thick cut Salted French Fries are golden on the outside and fluffy on the inside.",
      "price": 7,
      "slug": "french-fries-medium-80002"
    },
    {
      "itemId": 80003,
      "name": "FRENCH FRIES LARGE",
      "description": "More delicious than ever, our signature piping hot, thick cut Salted French Fries are golden on the outside and fluffy on the inside.",
      "price": 8,
      "slug": "french-fries-large-80003"
    }
  ],
  "slug": "french-fries-80001",
  "sequence": 8
}
```

The legacy system of the client was designed poorly and they are requiring an api that properly formats the data into a more granularized format. I was trying to figure out as to how do this. Please take note that the original array has more items than my example and I should loop through each one of them. Should I rebuild the data from scratch? Or is there a better way of doing this while looping through the array?

Comment: Instead of additional processing on the data and reformatting it using a loop on a huge data everytime, it sounds better if you rebuild your original array according to your convenience.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @RossWilson Laravel 5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `Collections` and do something like:

```
$data = collect(json_decode($data, true))
    ->map(function ($item) {
        return collect($item);
    })
    ->groupBy(function ($item) {
        return trim(str_replace(['SMALL', 'MEDIUM', 'LARGE'], '', $item['name']));
    })
    ->map(function ($items) {

        if ($items->count() > 2) {

            return $items;
        }

        $parent = $items->first()->except('price');
        $parent->put('itemModifiers', $items);

        return $parent;
    });
```

If you would prefer something a little shorter for the last `map` you could inline it :

```
->map(function ($items) {
    return $items->count() < 2 ? $items : $items->first()->except('price')->put('itemModifiers', $items);
});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
{"FRENCH FRIES":[{"itemId":80001,"name":"FRENCH FRIES SMALL","description":"More delicious than ever, our signature piping hot, thick cut Salted French Fries are golden on the outside and fluffy on the inside.","price":6,"slug":"french-fries-small-80001"},{"itemId":80002,"name":"FRENCH FRIES MEDIUM","description":"More delicious than ever, our signature piping hot, thick cut Salted French Fries are golden on the outside and fluffy on the inside.","price":7,"slug":"french-fries-medium-80002"},{"itemId":80003,"name":"FRENCH FRIES LARGE","description":"More delicious than ever, our signature piping hot, thick cut Salted French Fries are golden on the outside and fluffy on the inside.","price":8,"slug":"french-fries-large-80003"}],"CRINCKLE WEDGES":[{"itemId":80052,"name":"CRINCKLE WEDGES SMALL","description":"CRINCKLE WEDGES SMALL","price":7,"slug":"crinckle-wedges-small-80052","sequence":14},{"itemId":80053,"name":"CRINCKLE WEDGES MEDIUM","description":"CRINCKLE WEDGES MEDIUM","price":8,"slug":"crinckle-wedges-medium-80053","sequence":15},{"itemId":80054,"name":"CRINCKLE WEDGES LARGE","description":"CRINCKLE WEDGES LARGE","price":9,"slug":"crinckle-wedges-large-80054","sequence":16}]}
```

Code

```
$original = json_decode($original);
$output = array();
foreach ($original as $key => $row) {
  $newName = str_replace('SMALL', '', $row->name);
  $newName = str_replace('MEDIUM', '', $newName);
  $newName = str_replace('LARGE', '', $newName);
  $newName = trim($newName);
  if(in_array($newName,$output)){
    array_push($test[$newName], $row);
  }else{
     array_push($output, $newName);
     $test[$newName] = array();
     array_push($test[$newName], $row);
  }

}
echo "<h3>Output</h3><pre>"; print_r(json_encode($test)); exit;
```